# subview is always null in render method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Why `this.ImagesView` is null when you call `render` in `PostCreateView`?

It's always null even though it's been initialized.

```
PostCreateView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#create-product'),
    template: _.template(createTemplate),
    ImagesView: null,           
    initialize: function() {            
        this.ImagesView = new ImageViewCollection().render().el;
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.find('#images-collection').append(this.ImagesView)
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your code for `ImageViewCollection`?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Without it, we can only guess...

Comment: We don't even know how you call `render` of `PostCreateView`... I'd expect someone with 2k rep to share code required to reproduce the problem...

Comment: As you aren't returning `this` in the `PostCreateView.render`, I'd imagine that is the issue with `ImageViewCollection.render` and that's where your null comes from. http://backbonejs.org/#View-render

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/okku6no9/

Answer (score -1):

`this.ImagesView = new ImageViewCollection().render().el;` is bad convention.

What you should do is:

```
PostCreateView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#create-product'),
    template: _.template(createTemplate),
    ImagesView: null,           
    initialize: function() {            
        this.ImagesView = new ImageViewCollection()
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.find('#images-collection').append(this.ImagesView.render().el)
    }
});
```

## Update

`el` from `ImageViewCollection` is probably null because you are not returning `this` in the `render` method. Make sure it does this:

```
render: function(){
  // image view render logic
  return this
}
```

Comment: That's what I've been doing and it says this.ImagesView Cannot read property 'render' of null